# Induction Variable form other variable

Tags: powershell

i got some variables like

```
$FreeMonday = 10.10.17
$FreeTuesday= 10.10.17
$FreeWednesday= 10.10.17
```

and other variable with name Day OfWeek

```
$DayOfWeek = 'Tuesday'
```

now i wants to induction variable

```
$('Free'+ $DayOfWeek)
```

and gets information form variable

```
$FreeTuesday
```

how to do this?

Comment: `gv ('Free' + $DayOfWeek) -ValueOnly`, but do not do that. Use dictionary instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [PetSerAl suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744675/induction-variable-form-other-variable#comment80435517_46744675), you'd be better off with a dictionary (for example a hashtable) instead of dynamic variable names:

```
$Dictionary = @{
  FreeMonday = "10.10.17"
  FreeTuesday = "10.10.17"
  FreeWednesday = "10.10.17"
}
```

Now you can easily access the value by combining two strings:

```
$DayOfWeek = 'Tuesday'
$Dictionary["Free$DayOfWeek"]
```